# How can I make a google chrome extension for email?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, javascript-objects, manifest

I need to write a google chrome extension for email. When the user enters the recipient's address in the form and clicks the submit button, but the recipient's domain does not match the organization's domain (@vtb.uk), then a warning window is displayed with a Cancel and Submit buttons (button selectors are known). Please tell me how this can be done and what is required for this. Grateful for any help.

```
{
  const org = '@vtb.uk';
  addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const isSendButton == event.target.closest("tabindex"="570");
    if (!isSendButton) return;
    const addressNodes = document.querySelectorAll("tabindex"="100");
    const isValid = Array.from(addressNodes, (addressNode) => addressNode.textContent || addressNode.value)
      .flatMap((addressList) => addressList.trim().split(/[,;\s]+/))
      .every((address) => !address || address.endsWith(org));
    if (isValid) return;
 
    const isConfirmed = confirm('WARNING!');
    if (isConfirmed) return;
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopImmediatePropagation()
    event.stopPropagation()
  }, true);
}
```

I have this code but it doesn't work